# phpstorm xdebug eval fatal error on breakpoint cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0, xdebug, phpstorm

I have phpstorm 6.02 setup and configured for xdebug on osx (mountain lion) apache with a cakephp application.

If I set a breakpoint in my "AppController" it stops no problem and works.

When I setup a breakpoint in my UsersController, it doesnt stop and I see this error in my logs:

```
2013-06-02 15:07:16 Error: I GOT HERE TO INDEX FUNCTION 
2013-06-02 15:07:16 Error: current url is :/users
2013-06-02 15:07:16 Error: Fatal Error (4): parse error in [xdebug eval, line 1]
2013-06-02 15:07:16 Error: [FatalErrorException] parse error
Request URL: /users
Stack Trace:
#0 /Users/joelnylund/Sites/solutionstreet_maa/cakephp/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(184): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(4, 'parse error', 'xdebug eval', 1)
#1 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleError(4, 'parse error', 'xdebug eval', 1, Array)
#2 /Users/joelnylund/Sites/solutionstreet_maa/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(926): call_user_func('ErrorHandler::h...', 4, 'parse error', 'xdebug eval', 1, Array)
#3 /Users/joelnylund/Sites/solutionstreet_maa/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(899): App::_checkFatalError()
#4 [internal function]: App::shutdown()
#5 {main}
```

Any ideas what could be causing this and what I can do to fix it?

NOTE: I updated my xdebug to the latest rev (2.2.3) and now I dont get this error, but I also dont get a stop at any breakpoints.

Comment: I assume you looked at something like this:  http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

Comment: yes, thanks, I actually tried with Netbeans and same problem. I also upgraded xdebug to the latest version. Seems it must be something with my config or cake or both.

Comment: @Joelio We're using IntelliJ IDEA PHP plugin at work, and a co-worker tried installing xdebug 2.2.3 but it won't stop at any breakpoints. I'm using xdebug 2.2.1 and my breakpoints work. I'm wondering if xdebug 2.2.3 broke something in that regard.

Comment: Create a remote debugging log (xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log) and see what it runs as last command. Post the relevant bits to your question and I'll see what goes wrong. Alternatively, file a bug at http://bugs.xdebug.org

Comment: @Nate - I tried with 2.2.1 I think for starters and it didnt work, its weird because it work outside the normal controllers, I think it has to be something funky cake is doing to confuse the debugger...also maybe you dont have a softlink to your docroot and they do?

Comment: @Joelio Just to follow up, xdebug 2.2.3 does indeed work with IntelliJ IDEA. The paths in his debug configuration were wrong which is why it wasn't stopping at any breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have turned on xdebug in the browser and the page shows a green bug. Also, that phpstorm is showing the green telephone icon and the port is setup correctly in the settings for xdebug in phpstorm?

Have you tried also setting breakpoints sooner in the flow? It seems like it's erroring before your breakpoint possibly.

Set a breakpoint at
/Users/joelnylund/Sites/solutionstreet_maa/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/App.php line 899 and see if that breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to update PHPStorm, they released 8.0.x already. Anyways your last information sounds like you misconfigured Xdebug in your webservers configuration or use the wrong xdebug-library (xdebug libs must match with php-version in order to work)

Since recent versions of PHPStorm, you will see a popup asking to "connect" while browsing with active xdebug cookie and enabled debug-mode in PHPStorm. If that popup occurs your configurations and libs are fine.

There is a wide range of possible failures to cause xdebug not working properly. Thats why, in case of errors, you always might run a simple test, with a rudimentary "index.php" in your webservers root directory to ensure everything is working around your application.

After all, if your xdebug-configuration is correct and it is still not breaking, your breakpoint presumably wont be passed due to program termination or any other code-related processess such as "return;".